# How verified the shopping_cart table already have this item that show the message tell the user

Tags: php

How verified the shopping_cart table already have this product that show the message "This product already add to your shopping cart". If not insert the data.

I want to do if the customer and product is same then show the message.if not insert the data into shopping cart table

customer = is a user account

$id = is $_GET['id']

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM shopping_cart");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $pname = $row['product_name'];

    $res2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM product where id=$id");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $pname2 =$row2['product_name'];


    if($pname == $pname2)
    {
        $customer = $_SESSION['login_user'];

        if($row['customer'] == $customer)
        {
            echo "This product already add to your shooping cart";
        }
    }
    else{

    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM product where id=$id");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    $product_price = $row['product_price'];
    $customer = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $pimage = $row['product_image'];


    mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into shopping_cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,quantity,customer)
    values('$product_name','$product_price','$pimage','$qty','$customer')");

    header('location:cart.php');
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM shopping_cart");
> $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
>
> [...]
> ```

This will read only one entry from the shopping cart. And you don't know which one exactly, not even from which user. If you want to check if the item is already in the shopping cart you have to add a `WHERE` condition which reads the specific item, if it exists. It will look something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT
    id
FROM
    shopping_cart
WHERE
    product_id = ? AND
    customer = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $productId, $customerId);
$stmt->execute();
$found = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
if ($found) {
    /* already in */
} else {
    /* free to add */ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have solved my problem